# flutter speech_to_text recognizerNotAvailable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing an mobile app using flutter. This app uses the package "speech_to_text" for speech recognition.
When I test on my Huawei handy (Nova 5 pro), I get the following error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> PlatformException(recognizerNotAvailable, Speech recognition not
> available on this device, , null)

This error occurs when I call the initialize method.
I added following lines in "AndroidManifest.xml" direct under root node "manifest":

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Does this package support Huawei devices? Is it dependant on google-api?
Any help and suggestions are very appreciated!

Xinyu

Answer (score 5):

just add these lines below the permissions in your project android manifest

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 1):

In android->app->build.gradle **targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion** to **targetSdkVersion 28** this thing works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just set  `targetSdkVersion` in **build.gradle** to 28.

Comment: Also dont forget to install Google app [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=ru&gl=US)